# Finding user's bearing from current location in 2D plane iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-location

I am trying to access user's bearing from current location in my iOS app.

I am using below code to access it

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    heading = newHeading.trueHeading > 0 ? newHeading.trueHeading : newHeading.magneticHeading
}
```

However, it's not useful if we look at in 2D plane, where degree ranges from 0 to 360 clockwise. I want to send the bearing data to a different subscriber user through socket where an annotation with heading indicator(just like current location indicator with heading) on map can be displayed on iOS and Android. I am using a custom image which has heading indicator pointing up(12 O'Clock) to show on it on my other app.

Android has bearing which is the kind value I am looking for.

How can I get that value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading is determined by the magnetometer and indeed can't be used.  It's a static value.

Bearing is determined by comparing subsequent (GPS) locations.  It's a dynamic value over time.

iOS supplies bearing but names it 'course' with: [`locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager).

You must read `CLLocation`'s [`course` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423832-course).

Because course can only be determined if the mobile device is moving, the course accuracy depends on speed and GPS accuracy.  You must therefore use [`courseAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/3524338-courseaccuracy) to determine how/if you'll show this on the UI.

Comment: I guess your option is trying to determine with the use of 2 locations, previous and current one. That's something I dont want to do, if I can directly get it from user's current location. If Android can directly provide it I am sure iOS can do that too, I just couldn't figure out an easy way.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya It's been a while I looked at iOS location APIs. It seems that iOS does indeed supply bearing now.  See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for updating the answer. I tried that earlier but I dont know why the value is mostly -1. It updates to some positive number once in a while but then again goes back to -1. Not sure whats wrong with my code.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya The documentation I linked says: "A negative value indicates that the course information is invalid.".  If you're at home/office and your iOS isn't moving, of course iOS is unable to determine the `course`.  So there nothing wrong here; you must handle this situation as well.  Writing logic that deals with real world parameters like location isn't easy; there are many things & states you need to consider, handle and properly (re)present in the UI.  Check if the simulator allows setting a simulated `course`, like it does for location.

Comment: Thanks @meaning-matters. It works while I am on the move, though it stays -1 for some time initially but then it updates to correct value.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya I"m happy I could be of help to you.  Please make sure that you test for **negative values** and not just -1, because that's what's been specified in Apple's documentation.

Comment: There seems to still be some confusion on heading, bearing and course so let me try to explain. "Heading" as mentioned is where your vessel/vehicle/phone is pointing, "course" is the direction you are actually travelling, which may or may not be the same as heading. Bearing is a direction (from your present location) to any object you are interested in, which could be the destination or any other location. As such it is not possible to ask your phone for a bearing as it is completely dependent on what you want the bearing for; you will need to calculate this value based on map coordinates.

Comment: Or you can point the phone at the object, read the heading and that will be your bearing to that object.